# Is It OK to take vitamin tablets every day for long time?

Tags: lasting-effects-duration, omega-3, b-12-supplements, vitamin-d

What is the effect of taking vitamins tablets everyday for a long time? Will that make a person healthier? or harm the kidney? What if a person took them for about three or four months, Can He stop taking them after that period? Or his body will get used to take them?

I'm talking about these medicines specifically:

- Neurovit (Vit. B12).
- Vidrop (Vit. D).
- Omega 3.
- Ennervita (Vit. A and multivitamin and menerals).

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

This is really dependent on what dosage you take. Your body needs its micro nutrients, but a very important role of toxicity is: "Everything is toxic, depending the dose". For example, too high doses of healthy substances such as vitamin C can be carcinogenic. Health organisation such as the WHO or the CDC publish the advised intake amount of micro nutrients like the ones you've described. As long as you stay under on on this limit, everything must be okay. But let's be fair here, a healthy (Western) lifestyle is sufficient in providing you most of your micro nutrients. If you eat poorly of are concerned about this, consult a dietitian or your GP. After this, you can always turn to supplements

References:
National Institutes of Health. (2020, March 24). Vitamin D Fact Sheet for Health Professionals. Retrieved 12 June 2020, from https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/VitaminD-HealthProfessional/

World Health Organisation, & Food and Agricultural Organization of the United Nations. (2006, December). GUIDELINES ON FOOD FORTIFICATION WITH MICRONUTRIENTS (92 4 159401 2). https://doi.org/10.1002/14651858.CD004514.147.

Dutch Ministry of Health. (2011). Response of the Ministry of Health, Welfare and Sport (The Netherlands) on the Discussion Paper on the setting of maximum and minimum amounts for vitamins and minerals in foodstuffs. . The Hague, The Netherlands: Dutch Government.

Weggemans, R. M., Kromhout, D., & van Weel, C. (2013). New dietary reference values for vitamin D in the Netherlands. European Journal of Clinical Nutrition, 67(6), 685. https://doi.org/10.1038/ejcn.2013.55